# How to run ZAP scan in command line?

Tags: owasp, zap, penetration-testing

I am running pen test on asp.net core web app using the tool OWASP ZAP. When I am running the test using the windows app of Owasp ZAP, the tests are running fine and giving results but when I am trying to run the tests using command line I am seeing this exception.

```
raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001CCBD907D60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Why is this happening and how to correct this?

I changed the ZAP_PATH environment variable to the folder where zap.sh is located. Now I am getting a different exception:

```
 raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Comment: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it" that sounds pretty relevant. Have you tried to connect to the target app from the command line using a tool like `curl` ?
How are you starting ZAP? You shouldn't need to set ZAP_PATH

Comment: I suppose curl is a Linux command. I am starting zap using: zap-cli active-scan "website url" @SimonBennetts

Comment: Curl is available on pretty much every platform you can think of. FYI the zap-cli is a third party tool and not something supported by the Zap core team. The ways we recommend you automate ZAP are detailed on https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/automate/

Comment: @SimonBennetts  Can I start a active scan of a website using powershell script.

Comment: Yes, but it all depends on exactly what you want to do. The link I posted above shows all of the recommended options. You can run an active scan from any command line but you wont get as much control as if you either use the packaged scans or drive the ZAP API directly. The Automation Framework will be the recommended option but thats still at an early stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation [here](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/cmdline/) and [here](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/quick-start/cmdline/) I managed to run the basic scan from Windows command line.

From the directory where the ZAP is installed, in my case `C:\Program Files\OWASP\Zed Attack Proxy` run the following command:

```
PS C:\Program Files\OWASP\Zed Attack Proxy> java -jar zap-2.10.0.jar -cmd -quickurl http://example.com/ -quickprogress
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use zap docker image run run the test

**Baseline Scan**

```
docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-baseline.py -t http://google.com
```

**Full Scan**

```
docker run -t owasp/zap2docker-stable zap-full-scan.py -t http://google.com
```